# Css will not display in webpage, after adding it in style.css in child theme

Tags: css, child-theme

I have just started using wordpress again, after a long delay and cannot remember if I am putting the css in the child theme correctly. I placed a tiny piece of css code to display. I have put it in the style.css in the child theme, but it will not show.
I have created the child theme with the Astra generator, so it must be correct.

```
/**
Theme Name: Astra Child
Author: Brainstorm Force
Author URI: http://wpastra.com/about/
Description: Astra is the fastest, fully customizable & beautiful theme suitable for blogs, personal portfolios and business websites. It is very lightweight (less than 50KB on frontend) and offers unparalleled speed. Built with SEO in mind, Astra comes with schema.org code integrated so search engines will love your site. Astra offers plenty of sidebar options and widget areas giving you a full control for customizations. Furthermore, we have included special features and templates so feel free to choose any of your favorite page builder plugin to create pages flexibly. Some of the other features: # WooCommerce Ready # Responsive # Compatible with major plugins # Translation Ready # Extendible with premium addons # Regularly updated # Designed, Developed, Maintained & Supported by Brainstorm Force. Looking for a perfect base theme? Look no further. Astra is fast, fully customizable and beautiful theme!
Version: 1.0.0
License: GNU General Public License v2 or later
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
Text Domain: astra-child
Template: astra
*/



#header { color: blue;
}
```

the functions.php file is as follows:

```
<?php
/**
 * Astra Child Theme functions and definitions
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/theme-functions/
 *
 * @package Astra Child
 * @since 1.0.0
 */

/**
 * Define Constants
 */
define( 'CHILD_THEME_ASTRA_CHILD_VERSION', '1.0.0' );

/**
 * Enqueue styles
 */
function child_enqueue_styles() {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'astra-child-theme-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array('astra-theme-css'), CHILD_THEME_ASTRA_CHILD_VERSION, 'all' );

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'child_enqueue_styles', 15 );
```

Comment: If you use the browser tools to inspect the `id="header"` element, do you see your rules? They might not be applied because other rules' selectors are more precise than yours.

Comment: I tried adding just h1 { color: blue } then <h1> tag in the text heading. That does not work either.

Comment: If you're sure your styles are specific enough to apply, you may be running into a caching issue. Viewing your page source and searching for your child theme's stylesheet name should tell you whether or not the CSS file is being enqueued as expected, and if you then open that CSS file to check whether your updated styles are there, that will tell you whether they are cached.

Comment: I don't see the child theme stylesheet name in the source. Only see <script src=http://webyardcraft.local/wp-content/themes/astra/assets/js/minified/frontend.min.js?ver=3.7.5 id="astra-theme-js-js"></scripts>  I have gone to more tools and cleared the browsing data, is that what you mean, when you say cached. The css is output is still not showing. Could it may be because I pasted my content from a text editor like notepad++. Pasted the content into wordpress. It is enqueued correctly as above from the astra generator.

Comment: @SpencerHalstead Do you see the `<link>` for astra's main CSS? Can you share (by editing the question) how it looks?

Comment: No, there is no css from the child theme showing in the source. I don't have a link, as this site is on local by flywheel on my computer. Its not live. Maybe its because it local by flywheel, I will try upload the child theme on my live wordpress site, and see if it works there.

Comment: @SpencerHalstead That is not what I meant. In your enqueue call, you define `astra-theme-css` as a dependency. This means, your CSS will only ever be loaded if `astra-theme-css` is loaded as well. There could be a reason the main CSS is not loaded, and then your styles won't be loaded either. Without being able to see it live, it is almost impossible to know.

Comment: Thanks, will get back to you, just trying to upload child theme to live site, having problems there, as get message saying package could not be installed, no valid plugins found.